# Node JS Express include/import/export

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, import, module

Okay, so basically I'm trying to learn and get a hang on the export/import modules in Node. I have created a `app.js` which contains, everything. To make the `app.js` file a little cleaner and more readable I'm trying to include a `.js` file from another folder (`middleware/sass.js)`, how would I do that?

My `sass.js` file looks like this:

```
let sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');

app.use(
    sassMiddleware({
        src: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/scss'),
        dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
        debug: true,
        indentedSyntax: false,
        outputStyle: 'compressed',
        prefix: '/css'
    })
);
```

How do I "include" that in `app.js` without having it all there? I would say I try to do something like the **PHP** `include()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either have application instance in separate module, so it could be imported in multiple places:

*index.js*

```
require('./sass');
const app = require('./app');
app.listen(...);
```

*app.js*

```
...
const app = express();
module.exports = app;
```

*sass.js*

```
const app = require('./app');
...
app.use(...);
```

Or use dependency injection and wrap all parts that depend on application instance with a function:

*index.js*

```
const app = require('./app');
require('./sass')(app);
app.listen(...);
```

*sass.js*

```
...
module.exports = app => {
  app.use(...);
};
```

Comment: This made more sense to me. Thanks! Looks like ill go for the first option here.